# what is the difference between isomorphic and birational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_algebraic_varieties):

> In algebraic geometry, a morphism between algebraic varieties is a function between the varieties that is given locally by polynomials. It is also called a **regular map**. A morphism from an algebraic variety to the affine line is also called a **regular function**. A regular map whose inverse is also regular is called biregular, and they are isomorphisms in the category of algebraic varieties. Because regular and biregular are very restrictive conditions – there are no non-constant regular functions on projective varieties – the weaker condition of a **rational map** and **birational maps** are frequently used as well.

What is an example of two varieties $X$ and $Y$ over the field $k=\mathbb{Q}$ that are birational, but not isomorphic?

---

just a few more details if possible?

E.g. $X  = \{ y^2 - x^3 = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{A}^2 $ and $Y = \{ y -x^2 = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{A}^2 $.
What would be the maps $f : X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ ? Why are they birational and not inverse.

Comment: $y^2=x^3$ and $y=x^2$.

Comment: The usual example with $k=\Bbb C$ is that $\Bbb A^n$ is birational with $\Bbb P^n$ via the map $x\mapsto [x;1]$, the inverse of which is the affine chart $[a;\beta]\mapsto \frac a\beta$ defined for $\beta\ne0$. Yet, a morphism from $\Bbb P^n$ to $\Bbb A^m$ must be constant. I don't know if it carries on to the rational case.

Comment: Send the point $(x,y)$ of $y=x^2$ to the point $(x_1,y_1)=(y,xy)$ of $y_1^2=x_1^3$. The inverse is rational $(x,y)=(y_1/x_1,x_1)$. For biregular maps, the lack of tangent of $y^2=x^3$ at $(0,0)$ doesn't get removed.

Comment: @scentofthetrees Why not make your answer into an answer?

Comment: @AlexKruckman It is an answer. If you mean inputting it in a different box of the webpage, then no reason. You can do that if you like.

Comment: @scentofthetrees When a complete answer to a question is given in the comments, it usually discourages others from posting answers in the answers section. Then it's not possible for an answer to be accepted, so it will still show up in the list of unanswered questions, etc. So it's desirable from the point of view of site maintenance to use comments for comments and answers for answers. Maybe you don't care about this, in which case I apologize for being pedantic! But since I see you're relatively new here, I figure you might just be unaware of this issue / distinction.